# Meat, metal and Mediterraneans

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. One heavy metal group's farewell (5)
5. Actor who won an Oscar for taking off clothes in *Ice Age* (4)
7. Way to pay for immigration paperwork? (4)
10. Unfinished show makes permanent substitutions (13)
11. One small piece of land by endless sea? (4)
12. Confess about killing, essentially showing weapon (5)
15. Described being followed around: "Erratic, out of control" (13)
17. Meat-based sauce commonly served with pasta in Nicaragua (4)
20. Nationalists in movement holding last of rebel bases (13)
22. Animal's right to authorize me to be a wolf's father and a horse's mother? (4)
23. Twisted criminal, having stolen old paintings, at last lead to places where prisoners are held (5)
24. Rolling dice to get money (4)
25. T. Roosevelt initially replaced humanitarian leader in part of SE Asia – Theodore's taught to think uncritically? (13)
30. Fill up stomach? Firstly, eat bananas (4)
31. Delusional people from EU country switched sides after being caught by Ms. 5 across, dancing (13)
35. Somewhat serious, no-nonsense people who look down on others (5)
36. Ottomans originally ruled over Mediterranean city (4)
37. Relative putting backside all over new linen, showing lack of hygiene (13)
38. River crossed by gay man (4)
39. Hint about final conclusion? (4)
40. County's executives evacuated by Congress (5)

**Down**
2. Antenna is acquired by Dutch Shell (4)
3. Actress Fisher, among others, harbouring several extremists (4)
4. Maybe Carmen and supporter own company that makes calculators working in a functional way (13)
5. Related to computing engineer, I call UCLA a ton (13)
6. Having potential of being made more widely applicable, military leader bails out private in the end (13)
7. Terminate employment, having been written up being involved in six questionable actions, showing proofs (13)
8. Filthy dwelling reportedly leads to bacterial infection (4)
9. Ideas produced separately (5)
12. Epic story of Alura's origin (Krypton or something like that?) coming up (4)
13. Great courage shown by Greek character in Stephen King's book (4)
14. Pair of paratroopers protecting boundaries of Senegal's capital (4)
15. It's hot or cold, they say (5)
16. Unnamed authors participating in ban on smoking (5)
18. The writer would cut from Sunshine State's flowers (5)
19. Territory with sierra containing Ecuador's capital, but not Lima (5)
21. Vicious enemies gutted opposing factions (5)
26. Pink Floyd song describing Newfoundland and Labrador? (4)
27. Gaps between mountains belonging to us not displayed in flag (4)
28. Brazilian samba musician reaches finals, getting more than one Grammy (4)
29. Targaryen's heart is consumed by gloaty, fearsome dragon (5)
32. Ten lost on top of a Mediterranean peak (4)
33. Stable females rejected male Olympian? (4)
34. Piece of luggage missing? Legal action! Legal action! (4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Comment: The wordplay for 10A and 25A is very nice! The surface for 15D is also pretty smooth, and 5A is just silly (even though I might quibble slightly with the connector).

Comment: Well done, and thanks for the feedback! This was kind of an experiment on how many full-length answers one could have in the grid. I was pretty pleased with how easily-clueable all of the long answers turned out to be - even the one 13-letter anagram *could* have been clued differently without making the clue unreasonably wordy. I was kind of expecting this one to take a bit longer than it did, but I guess I should have learned by now :P